# XML feed pagination in PHP

Tags: php, xml, pagination

I'm trying to do a pagination with an XML feed but I can only get the first 20 results instead of the 44 results for example depending on the keyword search.

```
$totalResults = $xml->totalresults;

// Pagination
$items_total = $totalResults;
$max_pages = ceil($items_total / $per_page);    
$page = array_slice($items, $per_page * intval($_GET['p']) - 1, $per_page);

if($_GET['p'] > 1) {
    $prev_link = '<a href="?q='.urlencode(strtolower($_GET['q'])).'&city='.urlencode(strtolower($_GET['city'])).'&p='.($_GET['p']-10).'"> &laquo; Previous </a>';
}

if($_GET['p'] < $max_pages) {
    $next_link = '<a href="?q='.urlencode(strtolower($_GET['q'])).'&city='.urlencode(strtolower($_GET['city'])).'&p='.($_GET['p']+10).'"> Next &raquo;</a>';
}

<div><?php echo $prev_link; ?> <?php echo $next_link; ?></div>
```

**Here is the error I got:**

*Warning: array_slice() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in...*

I'm not sure what to pass in "$items"? I've seen a lots of examples but mainly from data coming from database. If someone could please point me to the right direction.

Comment: Just to mention that I have the $per_page variable set to 10 and that the XML feed has a "start" parameter set to &start=".(isset($_GET['p']) ? ''.urlencode(strtolower($_GET['p'])).'' : '0')."

Comment: `$items` should be whatever list of items you're trying to show a page of; where you get that from (and what you call the variable) is entirely up to you